# How can I modify a control in the selected tab - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, pointers, browser

I have a tabcontrol named tabControl1, which includes tabs. Button1 adds a tab to it when clicked and adds a browser and then navigate it to google.com.
Button2 should be able to navigate the browser in the selected tab to the text inside Text1.

I could do this easily **if C# had pointers** like this:

```
WebBrowser* thebrowser;

Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
  TabPage newtab = new TabPage();
  WebBrowser newbrowser = new WebBrowser();
  newtab.Controls.Add(newbrowser);
  newbrowser.Navigate("google.com");
  newtab.Click+=delegate {thebrowser = &newbrowser;};
  tabControl1.TabPages.Add(newtab);
}

Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
  thebrowser->Navigate(Text1.Text);
}
```

That if C# had pointers. Now how can I achieve this with proper C# code?
I hope you understood my question and sorry for any errors.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Object references *are* pointers.  You simply need to implement the TabControl's SelectedIndexChanged event, use  theBrowser = (WebBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i'd probably go the `Dictionary<int,Webbrowser>` way. Something like:

```
Dictionary<int, WebBrowser> browsers = new Dictionary<int, WebBrowser>();

Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
     TabPage newtab = new TabPage();
     WebBrowser newbrowser = new WebBrowser();
     newtab.Controls.Add(newbrowser);
     newbrowser.Navigate("google.com");
     tabControl1.TabPages.Add(newtab);
     browsers.Add(tabControl1.TabCount-1, newbrowser);
}

Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
     browsers[tabControl1.SelectedIndex].Navigate(Text1.Text);
}
```

Comment: Greaat! Exactly what i wanted!

Comment: But I have a question, why does it treat the browser in the dictionary as a pointer/reference rather than as a copy? o.O

Comment: @StormBreaker Dictionary<TKey, TValue> class is implemented as a hash table. Read this if you want further information: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

For what I understand you need to have more than one tab, so more than one browser open at the same time, so a lobal variable will not work.

One way of doing it would be to search the browser on the selected tab.

```
Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control item in page.Controls)
    {
        if (item is WebBrowser)
        {
            ((WebBrowser)item).Navigate(Text1.Text);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this not an efficient solution, I mean, if I wanna add more stuff and update it, this would slow down.. I need a fast alternative to pointers..

Comment: For it to slow down you will need a lot of controls in the TabPage, hundreds of them. But another way would be creating a custom control, inheriting from tabpage and adding a browser property. Then you will just need  ((yourCustomClass)tabControl1.SelectedPage).browser.Navigate()